# VB.NET difficulty in COOKIES

Tags: .net, vb.net, authentication, cookies

I am new to VB.NET and I want to ask questions about  Cookies. Please do not downvote my question if it sounds silly. I do not mean to waste any of your precious time, but I could not find anything clear related to this in Google

`COOKIES`-> I want to store data in the computer of a user to check if he is logged in or not. I want to know if there is something called cookies or some other thing that can store info in the user's PC in VB.NET. If there is nothing related to that, then of course we will have to store info in the database and delete it for them to act like cookies. Please tell me if there is something you know. Any help surely will be appreciated.

Comment: Interesting question..No one will downvote your question @BenLind

Comment: Not downvoting because "it sounds silly"; downvoting because Googling "vb.net cookies" has an overview as the very first link.

Comment: @AdrianWragg, when I search `vb.net cookies` , the first link shows `asp.net cookies`

Comment: @BenLind Did you read it? There's a reason why Google chose that as the best match, as it answers most of your questions. You do know that VB.net is a language you can use to write asp.net sites in, I take it?

Comment: I did not know that @AdrianWragg , I am new to this language

Comment: @BenLind You should probably start with the very very basics then, before worrying about cookies; your question history shows that you're asking about a wide variety of topics without having spent any time on learning fundamentals.

Comment: @AdrianWragg, I was confusing visual studio with vb.net. My question was for visual studio

Comment: @BenLind I think you're still confused I'm afraid; your question *does* relate to VB.Net. Visual Studio is the editor you use to write your code in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies relate to web applications and so in the context of vb.net, you can use these when you create an ASP.NET web application or website

If you want to store information locally when you are using a desktop application there are many options:

- file (ini/xml/etc.)
- registry
- database, etc.

there are pros and cons to all of these